# Error in module (cModule) Test (id=1) during network setup: Class "FlatNetworkConfigurator" not found

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to run a simulation in omnet++ 4.6 and inet 4.
I made a network with a .ned file (see below) and a .ini but I get a confusing error which I can not unterstand.

test.ned

```
package test1;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.FlatNetworkConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.nodes.ethernet.EtherSwitch;
import inet.nodes.inet.Router;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;

//
// TODO auto-generated type
//
network Test
{
    @display("bgb=961,379");
    types:
    submodules:
        etherHost2: StandardHost {
            @display("p=89,249");
        }
        etherHost1: StandardHost {
            @display("p=746,179");
        }
        etherSwitch2: EtherSwitch {
            @display("p=341,233");
            gates:
                ethg[3];
        }
        etherHost3: StandardHost {
            @display("p=227,333");
        }
        etherHost4: StandardHost {
            @display("p=398,333");
        }
        etherSwitch3: EtherSwitch {
            @display("p=528,38");
            gates:
                ethg[2];
        }
        router: Router {
            @display("p=447,157");
        }
        router1: Router {
            @display("p=206,153");
        }
        configurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=73,87");
        }
    connections:
        router.ethg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(1000Mbps); } <--> etherSwitch3.ethg++;
        router1.ethg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(100Mbps); } <--> router.ethg++;
        etherSwitch2.ethg[0] <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(100Mbps); } <--> router1.ethg++;
        etherSwitch2.ethg[0] <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(100Mbps); } <--> etherHost2.ethg++;
        etherSwitch3.ethg[0] <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(100Mbps); } <--> etherHost1.ethg++;
        etherSwitch2.ethg[0] <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(100Mbps); } <--> etherHost3.ethg++;
        etherSwitch2.ethg[0] <--> DatarateChannel {  datarate = default(100Mbps); } <--> etherHost4.ethg++;
}
```

test.ini

```
[General]
network = Test

#configurator 
*.configurator.dumpAddresses = true
*.configurator.dumpTopology = true
*.configurator.dumpLinks = true
*.configurator.dumpRoutes = true

# Routing settings
*.*.ipv4.arp.typename = "GlobalArp"
*.*.ipv4.routingTable.netmaskRoutes = ""
*.router*.tcpType="TCP"
**.etherSwitch*.relayUnitType = "MACRelayUnit" #config für Switch

**.eth[*].mac.duplexMode = true
**.eth.typename="EthernetInterface"
*.etherHost*.tcpType = "TCP_none"
*.etherHost*.udpType ="UDP"
*.etherHost*.sctpType ="SCTP"

**.eth[*].queueType = "DropTailQueue" # in routers
**.eth[*].queue.dataQueue.frameCapacity = 10  # in routers
```

It would be nice if someone could help me, I already tried to use the IPv4NetworkConfigurator instead of the FlatNetworkconfigurator but that did not work.
I also set inet in the settings of the project as reference.

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWdtD.png)

Answer (score 0):

INET 4.0 requires OMNeT++ 5.4. If you try to use it with OMNeT++ 4.6 you can expect a ton of various errors.